# How can I align several items horizontally using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I tried to align several items by using two columns and positioning the text, icon, and line within the left column and the other text on the right column, but they don't align properly. It currently looks like [this](https://esquivelclapes.com) but it should look like the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqopW.png) attached. How can I fix this?

```
<div class="col-12">
  <h1 class="orange">LET'S RUB IT IN</h1>
  <h2>How Much?</h2>
</div>

<div class="col-6"> <!--left column-->
  <div class="circle side">
    <img src="./chemical@2x.png" alt="chemical" class="icon">  
  </div>
  <h5 class="side">1 Shot Glass<br>or 1 oz.</h5>
  <div class="line v side"></div> <!--vertical line-->
</div>

<div class="col-6"> <!--right[enter image description here][1] column-->
  <p>To fully cover your body, you'll need about 1 ounce of sunscreen or just enough to fill a shot glass.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is you aren't using the `.container > .row > .col` convention. You've skipped the `.container`, and are sometimes skipping the `.row`. Additionally, you are not using the grid for the section shown in your screenshot.

Refer to the Bootrap documentation when there are Bootstrap issues.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/

1. The first thing is you should wrap all/most of your `<body>` content in a `<div class="container-fluid">`.
2. Then add any missing `.rows`.

This is what you have:

[image]

This is what you should have:

[image]

3. Write the contents of that next section to match your design.

ex.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6" style="border-right: 2px solid orange;">
            <div class="circle side" data-sr-id="9" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1) 0s;">
               <img src="./chemical@2x.png" alt="chemical" class="icon">  
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-6">
            <h5 class="side">1 Shot Glass<br>or 1 oz.</h5>
            <div class="line v side"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>To fully cover your body, you'll need about 1 ounce of sunscreen or just enough to fill a shot glass. </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Refere Bootstrap Grid System
Here:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp
It will fix your problem